# Ping device behind second interface of same router

Tags: networking, ip, routing, ping

I have following setup Galaxy on8 (Android 6)with Wi-Fi hotspot on : 192.168.43.1

Xolo a500(android 4.0 rooted) connected to that Wi-Fi hotspot :192.168.43.23

And also same xolo a500 connected to pc (mint linux) via usb cable with usb tethering .. So for that connection xolo a500: 192.168.42.129 and Pc: 192.168.42.12

I can access shared folder of pc on xolo a500 via usb connection. But I can’t access the same on galaxy on8.

However if turn on some server app(mostly wifi file transfer type) on galaxy on8 and put its ip address on pc I can view that server's interface.. (I can download and upload files from pc to On8 in this setup by using such third party app)

Or in different word I can ping xolo a500 (with both address) and galaxy on8 from pc,

also I can ping pc and on8 from xolo a500, and i can ping xolo a500 from on8,

****But I can’t ping pc from galaxy on8.****(error : 'network unreachable') (so i cant view shared files of pc ....)

pc and xolo a500 are on 192.168.42.0/24 network

and xolo a500 and galaxy on8 are on 192.168.43.0/24 network..and I can’t merge these subnet..

This happens with both android device They have 192.168.43.* with Wi-Fi interface. And 192.168.42.* with usb interface..

another scene : then I made slight change on above setup , xolo a500 to pc via usb tethering so a500 : 192.168.42.129 and pc : 192.168.42.12

and Xolo a500 with Wifi hotspot on and Galaxy On8 connected to it..

so a500 : 192.168.43.1 Galaxy On8 : 192.168.43.31

I cant ping pc from On8(this time...the error is 'connection time out')

**** And I can't ping On8 from Pc ****

(I was able to do this on previous setup).

These details are same for win7 on same pc.

My main Goal on these setup are

1: Access shared Folder of pc in Galaxy On8

2: Include Sony Bravia Smart Tv in this setup(on wifi network) to play media files stored in pc....

(I don’t want to root my Galaxy on8,but xolo a500 is rooted ,if any root command were to be executed on xolo a500)

( routing tables : in xolo a500 on both setup only these two entries..

192.168.43.0/24 via 192.168.43.1 on wlan0

192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.42.129 on rndis0)

in pc

default via 192.168.42.129 on usb0 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.42.129 on usb0

on Galaxy On8 on both setup

192.168.43.0/24 via 192.168.43.1 on wlan0 )

My question is this If I can ping galaxy on8 from pc then

*** why can’t I ping PC from On8 ?

(I mostly covered all info but if you need any additional info please ask me before downvoting, thanks in advance..)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay thanks for your effort but here is the perfect solution i found.

i made it possible on second setup

that is xolo to pc via usb tethering...as well as xolo as wifi hotspot and Galaxy on8 connected to xolo via wifi...

i run iptables -L on xolo a500
and found that  iptable was set to DROP for FORWARD policy.

then I  Downloaded AFWall+ to my xolo a500
ticked wifi ,ethernet for just DHCP and DNS from all list...
from option->apply and then option->Enable Firewall

and then I was able to ping my Galaxy on8 from My PC .
as well as Pc Fron my Galaxy On8.

then I shared my F: drive...
and gave ip address of pc to Xplore's Lan tool 
and i was able to view that drive in Xplore of Galaxy On8...

i even transferred file(700mb) from On8  to F: drive ..
Finally Done....

Answer (score 1):

What you have is this:
[image]

The PC is behind a NAT, just like a router, meaning that the Galaxy on8 phone can't see anything other than the Xolo a500, since it is hiding the PC behind it's own address.

The PC on the other hand, is able to see the Galaxy on8, since the Xolo a500 is translating the internal IP (192.168.42.x) to the "external" IP (192.168.43.x).

The best thing to do would be to connect all three devices to the same network. So one of the following:

- Connect the PC to the same hotspot as the Galaxy on8 is using
- Buy a wireless router and use that as a common network, connecting all three devices to it.

Comment: Xolo A500 has all amazing ANDROID OS

Comment: How do you.make this beautiful diagram?

Comment: I used https://www.draw.io/